# There's no immersion from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to show that there's no immersion from $S^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$, that is, there exists no smooth function $f:S^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that $df|_p$ is injective $\forall p \in S^n$.

By simple calculation, we know that it's equivalent to say that after writing $f = (f_1,f_2,\cdots, f_n)$, the matrix $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}|_p)_{i,j}$ has determinant $\neq 0\, \forall p \in S^n$ where $x_i$ are local coords of $S^n.$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832258/show-that-there-exists-no-immersion-f-of-s-1-into-r1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An immersion would be an open mapping, so its image would be both open and compact...

Comment: Is every immersion an open mapping? This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/436573/360587 suggests not. (The counter example is the canonical immersion from R^1 into R^2. The domain is open but the image is a line in R^2 which is not open.)

Comment: An immersion between manifolds of the **same** dimension is an open map. @AryamanJal

Comment: Oh sorry, of course you meant same dimension in the answer above. Because such immersions would be in fact be local diffeomorphisms and in particular submersions which we know are open.